# Is there any documentation on use of filters for the BalancedPayments API

Tags: api, balanced-payments

The API documentation on customers (and elsewhere) states there are 'Available Query Filters', listing various options, yet the 'Fetch a Customer' page describes only how to fetch a customer by their ID. I've looked through the API documentation to see if there is anything pertaining to fetching by filters and there doesn't appear to be anything there.  The source code unit test SuiteTest.php does have a couple of examples.  Is this all there is?

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is not. All client libraries are capable of filtering and sorting however.

We have [an open issue](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-docs/issues/383) to address this in the documentation.

Here's how you can do it in the Ruby, PHP and Python client libraries

### Ruby

```
Balanced::Customer.find(email: 'john@example.org')
```

### PHP

```
Balanced\Account->query()->filter(Balanced\Account::$f->email_address->eq("john@example.org"))
```

### Python

```
balanced.Customer.query.filter(email='john@example.org')
```

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is relatively old, but I was wondering if the same thing was possible with events? 
Instead of using their webhooks, I was going to fetch the events manually and filter them by the created_at date if possible to limit it to only the last day's events. I am using the Node.js balanced payments package. Here is currently how I fetch the events:

```
balanced.marketplace.events.range(offset,pageSize)
```